# Will I get a faster parser using spirit X3 when I use the expect operator

Tags: c++, parsing, c++14, boost-spirit, boost-spirit-x3

In spirit X3 I can build a parser like this:

```
const auto p = ("Number:" >> x3::_int)
             | ("String:" >> +x3::alpha);
```

If I know after the string `Number` comes a int and after `String` a string all the time I can use the `>` to say after `Number` only comes a number and so on.

```
const auto p = ("Number:" > x3::_int)
             | ("String:" > +x3::alpha);
```

For me the difference is if the parser fails to parse the input an exception is throw.

Now my question is, should I use the `>` operater over the `>>` operater whenever possible? Is the parser which will be generated using `>` faster then the one only using the `>>` operator?

Comment: No – `>` is `>>` plus a `throw` if parsing fails.

Comment: If you ever wonder "What is faster", just measure it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should always just profile things.

Regardless:

> Will I get a faster parser using spirit X3 when I use the expect operator

Only to the extent that it prevents backtracking alternatives, but if you needed that it's not doing the same anyways.